# Multiple await in for loop (no-await-in-loop)

Tags: node.js, typescript, for-loop, async-await, eslint

I have this function where I disabled eslint warning but I would like to improve the code. I understand that I should use promise.All(), but I am unsure how to proceed since I have two await in the for loop.

```
const getBatchLogsByHash = async (
  chainId: number,
  rpc: string,
  batch: BlockRange,
) => {
  const firstBlock = batch.startBlock;
  const lastBlock = batch.endBlock;
  const logs: Array<Log> = [];
  /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
  for (let i = firstBlock; i <= lastBlock; i += 1) {
    const block = await ethers.fetchBlock(chainId, rpc, i);
    const blockLogs = await ethers.fetchLogsByBlockHash(
      chainId,
      rpc,
      block.hash,
    );
    logs.push(...blockLogs);
  }
  return logs;
};
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you use some sort of `Promise.all` instead of your for-loop, you have no guarantee whatsoever, in what order the requests are executed. Ie your `logs` may appear in arbitrary order ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await` inside the promise executor in order to wait before you resolve the promise. `Promise.all` then allows you to execute the `lastBlock - firstBlock + 1` `ethers` operations in parallel. Since the order in which they *finish* cannot be predicted, you cannot use `logs.push(...blockLogs)`. Use `concat` instead to concatenate the `blockLogs` to which the individual promises resolve in the order in which you *started* these promises.

```js
var promises = [];
for (let i = firstBlock; i <= lastBlock; i += 1)
  promises.push(new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    const block = await ethers.fetchBlock(chainId, rpc, i);
    const blockLogs = await ethers.fetchLogsByBlockHash(
      chainId,
      rpc,
      block.hash,
    );
    resolve(blockLogs);
  }));
var logs = Array.prototype.concat.call(...await Promise.all(promises));
return logs;
```

But the following simpler code using `.then` would be equivalent:

```js
var promises = [];
for (let i = firstBlock; i <= lastBlock; i += 1)
  promises.push(ethers.fetchBlock(chainId, rpc, i).then(
    block => ethers.fetchLogsByBlockHash(
      chainId,
      rpc,
      block.hash,
    )
  ));
var logs = Array.prototype.concat.call(...await Promise.all(promises));
return logs;
```

Comment: As a quick note, I had to use this syntax to get rid of any warning
`var logs = ([] as any[]).concat(...await Promise.all(promises));`

Comment: You could also use `var logs = (await Promise.all(promises)).flat()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)